# In Haskell, express constraints on class header or class methods?

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

I've recently realized this thing:

On the one hand:

Constraints specified on a class header, must be specified again on an instance of that class, but any use of that class as a constraint somewhere else does not need to reimport the class constraints. They are implicitly satisfied.

```hs
class (Ord a) => ClassA a where methodA :: a -> Bool -- i decided to put constraint (Ord a) in the class header
instance (Ord a) => ClassA a where methodA x = x <= x   -- compiler forces me to add (Ord a) => in the front
```

```hs
class OtherClassA a where otherMethodA :: a -> Bool 
instance (ClassA a) => OtherClassA a where otherMethodA x = x <= x && methodA x -- i don't need to specify (Ord a) so it must be brought implicitly in context
```

On the other hand:

A constraint specified in a class method, does not need to be specified again on an instance of that class, but any use of that class as a constraint somewhere else, needs to reimport specific constraints for method used.

```hs
class ClassB a where methodB :: (Ord a) => a -> Bool -- i decided to put constraint (Ord a) in the method
instance ClassB a where methodB x = x <= x  -- i don't need to specify (Ord a) so it must be implicitly in context
```

```hs
class OtherClassB a where otherMethodB :: a -> Bool 
instance (ClassB a, Ord a) => OtherClassB a where otherMethodB = methodB -- compiler forced me to add (Ord a)
```

What is the motivation for those behaviors? Would it not be preferrable to be explicit about constraints at all times?

More concretely when I have a set of conditions I know all methods in a type class should satisfy, should I write the conditions, in the type class header, or in front of each method?
Should I write constraints in a type class definition at all?

Comment: Side note: in your first example, `class (Ord a) => ClassA a` means every instance of `ClassA` is an instance of `Ord`, and `instance (Ord a) => ClassA a` means every instance of `Ord` is an instance of `ClassA`. That makes `ClassA` superfluous, as it has exactly the same instances as `Ord`, and so you can drop the class and replace `methodA` with a function of type `Ord a => a -> Bool`.

Comment: @duplode I think my example could be modified, so that the class contains several functions that satisfy some laws, so that you can't get rid of the class. or can you?

Comment: I think I understand the difference of behavior between the two cases now, but not sure what the best practice is. I am mostly interested in knowing what criterion should tell me what the better design is.

Comment: Even with several methods, if you want  an `instance Ord a => ClassA a` you can only have one implementation of those methods (as, in the absence of overlapping instances, that is the only instance you can write), and you can't use anything more specific than the `Ord` methods in said implementation (as you don't know anything else about `a`). That being so, `ClassA` would buy you very little.

Comment: Your example code would be more realistic if you defined the `instance` for a SpecificType instead of a parametric type like `a`. The problems you're discussing only happen if you're defining an instance for a parametric type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Here's my general advice on constraints in class declarations and instance definitions.  See below for a longer explanation and a detailed description of your examples.

1. If you have classes with a logical relationship such that it is logically impossible for a type to belong to class `Base` without belonging to class `Super`, use a constraint in the class declaration, like so:

   ```
    class Super a => Base a where ...
   ```

   Some example:

   ```
    -- all Applicatives are necessarily Functors
    class Functor f => Applicative f where ...
    -- All orderable types can also be tested for equality
    class Eq f => Ord f where ...
    -- Every HTMLDocument also supports Document methods
    class Document doc => HTMLDocument doc where ...
   ```
2. Avoid writing instances that apply to all types, with or without constraints.  With a few exceptions, these usually point to a design flaw:

   ```
    -- don't do this
    instance SomeClass1 a
    -- or this
    instance (Eq a) => SomeClass1 a
   ```

   Instances for higher-order types make sense though, and use whatever constraints are necessary for the instance to compile:

   ```
    instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) where
      compare (x1,x2) (y1,y2) = case compare x1 x2 of
        LT -> LT
        GT -> GT
        EQ -> compare x2 y2
   ```
3. Don't use constraints on class methods, except where a class should support different subsets of methods on different types, depending on the constraints available.

#### Long Answer

Constraints in class declarations and instance definitions have different meanings and different purposes.  A constraint in a class declaration like:

```
class (Big a) => Small a
```

defines `Big` as a "superclass" of `Small` and represents a type-level claim of a logical necessity:  any type of class `Small` is necessarily also a type of class `Big`.  Having such a constraint improves type correctness (since any attempt to define a `Small` instance for a type `a` that doesn't also have a `Big` instance -- a logical inconsistency -- will be rejected by the compiler) and convenience, since a `Small a` constraint will automatically make available the `Big` class interface in addition to the `Small` interface.

As a concrete example, in modern Haskell, `Functor` is a superclass of `Applicative` which is a superclass of `Monad`.  All `Monad`s are `Applicative`s and all `Applicative`s are `Functor`s, so this superclass relationship reflects a logical relationship between these collections of types, and also provides the convenience of being able to use the monad (`do`-notation, `>>=`, and `return`), applicative (`pure` and `<*>`) and functor (`fmap` or `<$>`) interfaces using only a `Monad m` constraint.

A consequence of this superclass relationship is that any `Monad` instance must *also* be accompanied by an `Applicative` and `Functor` instance to provide evidence to the compiler that the necessary superclass constraints are satisfied.

In contrast, a constraint in an instance definition introduces a dependency of the specific, defined instance on another instance.  Most commonly, I see this used to define instances for classes of high-order types, like the `Ord` instance for lists:

```
instance Ord a => Ord [a] where ...
```

That is, an `Ord [a]` instance can be defined for any type `a` using lexicographic ordering of the list, **provided** that the type `a` itself can be ordered.  The constraint here does not (and indeed *could not*) apply to all `Ord` types.  Rather, the instance definition provides an instance for all lists by introducing a dependency on an instance for the element type -- it says that an `Ord [a]` instance is available for any type `a` that has an `Ord a` instance available.

Your examples are somewhat unusual, as one doesn't normally define an instance:

```
instance SomeClass a where ...
```

that applies to *all* types `a`, with or without additional constraints.

Nonetheless, what's happening is that:

```
class (Ord a) => ClassA a
```

is introducing a logical type-level fact, namely that all types of class `ClassA` are also of class `Ord`.  Then, you are presenting an instance of `ClassA` applicable to all types:

```
instance ClassA a
```

But, this presents a problem to the compiler.  Your class declaration has stated that is it logically necessary that all types of `ClassA` also belong to class `Ord`, and the compiler requires proof of the `Ord a` constraint for any instance `ClassA a` that you define.  By writing `instance ClassA a`, you are making the bold claim that all types are of `ClassA`, but the compiler has no evidence that all classes have the necessary `Ord a` instances.  For this reason, you must write:

```
instance (Ord a) => ClassA a
```

which, in words, says "all types `a` have an instance of `ClassA` *provided* an `Ord a` instance is also available".  The compiler accepts this as proof that you are only defining instances for the those types `a` that have the requisite `Ord a` instance.

When you go on to define:

```
class OtherClassA a where
  otherMethodA :: a -> Bool
instance (ClassA a) => OtherClassA a where
  otherMethodA x = x <= x && methodA x
```

since `OtherClassA` has no superclass, there is no logical necessity that types of this class are also of class `Ord`, and the compiler will require no proof of this.  In your instance *definition* however, you define an instance applicable to all types whose **implementation** requires `Ord a`, as well as `ClassA a`.  Fortunately, you've provided a `ClassA a` constraint, and because `Ord` is a superclass of `ClassA`, it is a logical necessity that any `a` with a `ClassA a` constraint also has an `Ord a` constraint, so the compiler is satisfied that `a` has both required instances.

When you write:

```
class ClassB a where
  methodB :: (Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

you are doing something unusual, and the compiler tries to warn by refusing to compile this unless you enable the extension `ConstrainedClassMethods`.  What this definition says is that there is no logical necessity that types of class `ClassB` also be of class `Ord`, so you're free to define instances that lack the require instance.  For example:

```
instance ClassB (Int -> Int) where
  methodB _ = False
```

which defines an instance for functions `Int -> Int` (and this type has no `Ord` instance).  However, any attempt to *use* `methodB` on such a type will demand an `Ord` instance:

```
> methodB (*(2::Int))
...  • No instance for (Ord (Int -> Int)) ...
```

This can be useful if there are several methods and only some of them require constraints.  The GHC manual gives the following example:

```
class Seq s a where
  fromList :: [a] -> s a
  elem     :: Eq a => a -> s a -> Bool
```

You can define sequences `Seq s a` with no logical necessity that the elements `a` be comparable.  But, without `Eq a`, you're only allowed to use a subset of the methods.  If you try to use a method that needs `Eq a` with a type `a` that doesn't have such an instance, you'll get an error.

Anyway, your instance:

```
instance ClassB a where
  methodB x = x <= x
```

defines an instance for all types (without requiring any evidence of `Ord a`, since there's no logical necessity here), but you can only use `methodB` on the subset of types with an `Ord` instance.

In your final example:

```
class OtherClassB a where
  otherMethodB :: a -> Bool
```

there's no logical necessity that a type of class `OtherClassB` also be a type of class `Ord`, and there's no requirement that `otherMethodB` only be used with types having an `Ord a` instance.  You could, if you wanted, define the instance:

```
instance OtherClassB a where
  otherMethodB _ = False
```

and it would compile fine.  However, by defining the instance:

```
instance OtherClassB a where
  otherMethodB = methodB
```

you are providing an instance for all types whose *implementation* uses `methodB` and so requires `ClassB`.  If you modify this to read:

```
instance (ClassB a) => OtherClassB a where
  otherMethodB = methodB
```

the compiler still isn't satified.  The specific method `methodB` requires an `Ord a` instance, but since `Ord` is not a superclass of `ClassB`, there is no logical necessity that the constraint `ClassB a` implies `Ord a`, so you must provide additionl evidence to the compiler that an `Ord a` instance is available.  By writing:

```
instance (ClassB a, Ord a) => OtherClassB a where
  otherMethodB = methodB
```

you are providing an instance that requires `ClassB a` (to run `methodB`) and `Ord a` (because `methodB` has it as an additional requirement), so you need to tell the compiler that this instance applies to all types `a` **provided** both `ClassB a` and `Ord a` instances are available.  The compiler is satisfied with this.

#### You Don't Need Type Classes to Delay Concrete Types

From your examples and follow-up comments, it sounds like you're (mis)using type classes to support a particular style of programming that avoids committing to concrete types until absolutely necessary.

(As an aside, I used to think this style was a good idea, but I've gradually come around to thinking it's mostly pointless.  Haskell's type system makes refactoring so easy that there's little risk to committing to concrete types, and concrete programs tend to be mostly easier to read and write than abstract programs.  *However,* many people have used this style of programming profitably, and I can think of at least one high-quality library (`lens`) that takes it to absolute extremes very effectively.  So, no judgement!)

Anyway, this style of programming is generally better supported by writing top-level polymorphic functions and placing the needed constraints on the functions.  There is usually no need (and no point) in defining new type classes.  This was what @duplode was saying in the comments.  You can replace:

```
class (Ord a) => ClassA where method :: a -> Bool
instance (Ord a) => ClassA where methodA x = x <= x
```

with the simpler top-level function definition:

```
methodA :: (Ord a) => a -> Bool
methodA x = x <= x
```

because the class and instance serve no purpose.  The main point of type classes is to provide ad hoc polymorphism, to allow you to have a single function (`methodA`) that has different implementations for different types.  If there's only one implementation for all types, that's just a plain old parametric polymorphic function, and no type class is needed.

Nothing changes if there are multiple methods, and usually nothing changes if there are multiple constraints.  If your philosophy is that data types should be characterized only by the properties they satisfy rather than by what they are, then the flip side of that is that functions should be typed to demand of their argument types only the properties that they need.  If they demand more than they need, they are prematurely committing to a more concrete type than necessary.

So, a class for, say, an orderable numeric key type with a printable representation:

```
class (Ord a, Num a, Show a) => Key a where
  firstKey :: a
  nextKey :: a -> a
  sortKeys :: [a] -> [a]
  keyLength :: a -> Int
```

and a single instance:

```
instance (Ord a, Num a, Show a) => Key a where
  firstKey = 1
  nextKey x = x + 1
  sortKeys xs = sort xs
  keyLength k = length (show k)
```

is more idiomatically written as a set of functions that constrain the type only based on the properties they require:

```
firstKey :: (Num key) => key
firstKey = 1

nextKey :: (Num key) => key -> key
nextKey = (+1)

sortKeys :: (Ord key) => [key] -> [key]
sortKeys = sort

keyLength :: (Show key) => key -> Int
keyLength = length . show
```

On the other hand, if you find it helpful to have a formal "name" for an abstract type and prefer the compiler's help in enforcing use of this type instead of just using type variables like "`key`" with evocative names, I guess you can use type classes for this purpose.  However, your type classes probably shouldn't have any methods.  You want to write:

```
class (Ord a, Num a, Show a) => Key a
```

and then a bunch of top-level functions that use the type class.

```
firstKey :: (Key k) => k
firstKey = 1

nextKey :: (Key k) => k -> k
nextKey = (+1)

sortKeys :: (Key k) => [k] -> [k]
sortKeys = sort

keyLength :: (Show k) => k -> Int
keyLength = length . show
```

Your entire program can be written this way, and no instances are actually needed until you get down to choosing your concrete types and documenting them all in one place.  For example, in your `Main.hs` program, you could commit to an `Int` key by giving an instance for a concrete type and using it:

```
instance Key Int
main = print (nextKey firstKey :: Int)
```

This concrete instance also avoids the need for extensions like undecidable instances and warning about fragile bindings.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, it is very clear. One thing that shocked me though, is your claim that instances like ```instance (Constraints a) => SomeClass a``` are bad.
I almost always write my intances that way, and almost never write instances for concrete types. My philosophy is to delay concrete types usage as much as possible, and specify all of them in one place. I believe types used should be characterised essentially by what properties they satisfy, and not by what they are. If you think this is wrong design I'd be happy to understand why.

Comment: Often what I do to have several instances is use newtypes wrappers, but still with a universal parametric newtype that must satisfy some constraints.

Comment: I feel its more the role of the standard library developpers, to provide instances for all concrete primitive types which in the end are gateways to compiler features.

Comment: I added a section to address this.  While I don't personally think that this approach to types is particularly worthwhile, at least in most Haskell programs, I don't think it's bad design.  But, this programming style is more idiomatically written using plain old polymorphism with constraints on top-level functions. and doesn't normally need any extra type classes.

Comment: I'd like to add that it's fine for class methods to mention other classes, as long as they constraint a *different* type variable than the class's type variable. `Traversable t`'s `traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` is a good example of that. The added constraint is on `f`, while the class variable is `t`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr  Thanks, I actually went too fast and agree that instance ```class (Constraints a) => SomeClass a```, is useless as it can be replaced by a single function. However do you also think it is useless to have for example: ```class (Constraints a) => SomeClass (SomeNewType(a))```  where a is unconstrained? Well from your answer you prefer concrete types..

Comment: @jam, I assume you meant `instance` rather than `class`.  Yes, `instance (Constraints a) => SomeClass (SomeNewType a)` can make a lot of sense.  A good library [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down) from `base` is `instance (Ord a) => Down (Ord a)` which reverses the order for any type.  Other nice examples are [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) and [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Product) used to wrap any `Num` type.